# Is this wall load bearing?

Tags: walls, removal, demolition

i recently bought a very old house and wanted to start renovating asap.

I want to take out this wall but i am unsure if its load bearing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the wall that does not connect to the ceiling? If so, it *can't* be load bearing...as there's no load to bear.

Comment: See [Load Bearing Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-bearing_wall) - *"A load-bearing wall (or bearing wall) is a wall that bears **a load resting upon it** ..."*

Answer (score 6):

The only thing bearing on that wall are shampoo bottles.
Knock away.  The wall is empty.  Note that the end of the porcelain tub is open,
so something will have to go back to cover it up.  When it's open you can inspect under the tub for horrors.

But you'll also want to remove the wall sheathing all around that tub, and read up about flashing and backer board.

Comment: to be fair, I think it's holding up the shower curtain rod as well.

Comment: and perhaps some dust.

Comment: If a wall is long or does not have other walls connecting to it at a corner, then a lower side wall may be bracing the main wall.    So **just** because a wall is not taking load from above does not mean it is safe to remove the wall.

Comment: That end wall design for tubs is common in houses of the era.  Given the size of the bathroom pictured (8-9 feet), a bearing function is not likely.  No buttresses, flying or otherwise.  The pictured wall holds up shampoo.